# Debian .bashrc: prompt PS1

Tags: bash, shell

Let's say I'm on a fresh install of Debian, Jessie (or Wheezy). As a regular user, I've got the prompt defined in the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file, eventually override by the one in my `/home/foobar/.bashrc`

Ok, cool, so I've got something like that: `foobar@myserver:~$`
Now, I'm trying to understand the code below:

```
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

As you can see, the PS1 variable (= the prompt) seems to be overrided again (cause yeah I'm in a `xterm`). But I can't get why we have another `$PS1` on the end of the line!

In order to get this, I've put 3 letters `a` `b` `c` in this line :

```
PS1="a\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]b$PS1 c"
```

And now, I have the strange prompt below:

```
abfoobar@myserver:~$  c
```

So it seems that the almost entire line is not use, everything between the brakets.

- Is that a sort of conditional statement?
- What is really the purpose of this line?
- Why the comment talk about the title of the xterm windows but seems
  to only override the PS1? I'm running this xterm through `PuTTY` ; in ubuntu, this line is quite different
  `PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'`

Comment: It is one of Debian's long standing faults to mess the files in the user home. The condition statement is Bash's parameter expansion, which is nicely explained here: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: This might be useful to understand how to tune the Bash prompt: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/

Comment: The `$PS1` at the end is there to allow PS1 to be previously defined and this just prepends text to it rather than replacing it.

Comment: @ceving Thanks. However, it does not cover the first char `\[\e]0;`. But @Nahuel Fouilleul got it ;)
@WilliamPursell yeah well it prepends nothing, that's why Im confused ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the part between `\[` `\]` seems to be an escape sequence which is handled by terminal : `ESC ]` which is named `OSC` for Operating System Commands in following link [xterm escape sequence](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)

```
OSC Ps ; Pt ST
      Set Text Parameters.  For colors and font, if Pt is a "?", the
      control sequence elicits a response which consists of the con-
      trol sequence which would set the corresponding value.  The
      dtterm control sequences allow you to determine the icon name
      and window title.
        Ps = 0  -> Change Icon Name and Window Title to Pt.
```

It is to change xterm window title.

As the window title contains the current working directory setting the prompt allows to update the title when changing directory after cd command.

Comment: Wow,i'm pretty impressed, where did you find this?!. So all this big line is only there to put in the `PS1` variable an escaped sequence *for* the terminal, but invisible *in* the prompt. That's insane. Thank you!

Comment: Note that the `\[...\]` pair is being used incorrectly; none of the shell's escape sequences (like `\u`, `\h`, etc) should be included, nor should any printable characters. As far as I can tell, the *only* thing that should be included is the `\e[0;` sequence.

Comment: from the link provided by @ceving, http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/xterm-title-bar-manipulations.html, gives the same example. It seems `\u` `\h` sequences are processed by shell before being sent to xterm, also `\e` or `\033` is replaced by `esc` ASCII 27 or 33 in octal.

Comment: @chepner well this line is by default here in every `bashrc` shipped in Debian ; II supposed they know what they are writing, right? ;)

Comment: I would never suppose that.